# model association or controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to create a rails app that allows users to submit information about their pets.  I've come to a point where my knowledge is limited and I don't know enough about what/how this could be done so I'm hoping this will be relatively easy to answer.

At the moment I have a model called Pet, this model currently stores basic information like name, picture etc but it also holds more specific data like type, breed, date of birth etc.  What I would like to be able to do is create a page that can match various records without having to be manually categorized if that makes sense so a users pet could be matched to other pets with the same breed, age etc.

I've read about nested models as I understand this information could be submitted to 2 models in one form but I am not sure whether this could be done directly in a separate controller which would only be visible to users with pets in these matched "groups" if that makes sense.

So in essence is it best practice to use 1 table to store all the information and just use a controller to match pets based on rows having the same values or would it be far simpler to have a form with a nested model and link 2 tables together?

The main feature needs to be matching without a user having to create a group or categorize pets so the second model would need to add id's to an array instead of just creating more and more rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used both one table and two tables.  The nice thing about two tables is you can perform additional queries on the details of the `pets` table and, say `pet_details` - plus, it keeps the tables smaller and easier to manage.

With a nested model, you wouldn't necessarily create a new controller unless you wanted to directly manipulate the data through the web or an API for your nested model.  The parent model `Pet` would handle all the manipulation of that data.  TL;DR - it basically just keeps it more organized.

Comment: Would that mean you'd be storing pet_id in an array which would check  the details before saving or just create a new row each time and do a find on the pet-details?

Comment: `pet_details` would `belong_to` `pets` and `pets` would `have_many` (or maybe `has_one`) `pet_details`.  In my mind, you'd be storing `pet_id` on `pet_details` and run any validations there before saving.  Does this answer your question?

Comment: My pleasure.  Let me know if you have additional questions. :)